# jmeter how to iterate/traverse multiple parameters (not variables)

Tags: jmeter

Suppose that I have a request:

```
http://ip:port/search
```

with multiple optional query parameters:

```
key1
key2
key3
```

I wanna test these parameters one by one, aka each parameter for one request, in ONE sampler instead of multiple samplers.

How could I do it? Thanks.

Comment: You can use CSV Data Set Config with multiple columns for all parameters per request

Comment: @user7294900 many thanks though you didn't answer but comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most commonly used test element for parameterization is [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config), if you store your query parameters to `keys.csv` file you can set up your test plan as follows:

[image]

and once done you can reference the value as `${key}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where required

[image]

This way JMeter will read next value from the file on each iteration of each thread (virtual user) and you will be able to use only one [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for checking multiple values from the CSV file:

[image]

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: quick and exact answer. many thanks!